# Explode data frame columns into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe `a` that I would like to split or explode to become dataframe `b` (the real dataframe `a` contains 90 columns).

I tried to look up for solutions to a problem similar to this but I did not find since it is not related to the values in cells but to the column names.

Any pointer to the solution or to using an existing function in the pandas library would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
# current df
a = DataFrame([{'ID': 'ID_1', 'A-1': 'a1', 'B-1':'b1','C-1':'c1', 'A-2': 'a2', 'B-2':'b2','C-2':'c2'}])

# desired df
b = DataFrame([{'ID': 'ID_1', 'A': 'a1', 'B':'b1', 'C':'c1'},
               {'ID': 'ID_1','A': 'a2', 'B':'b2','C':'c2'}])
```

current df
[image: current df]

desired df
[image: desired df]

One idea I have is to to split this dataframe into two dataframes (Dataframe 1 will contain columns from A1 to C1 and Dataframe 2 will contain columns from A2 to C2 ) rename the columns to A/B/C and than concatenate both. But I am not sure in terms of efficiency since I have 90 Columns that will grow over time.

Comment: do you have exactly 90 columns? do you have the same number of A,B,C variations?

Comment: For now I have 90 columns that can change to be more than that in the future. No I can have A-1 to A-6 but only D-1 to D-4, for example. Also I have other columns like ID with no variations but that need to be duplicated in every row just like ID-1 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) works well here assuming a small number of known stubnames:

```
b = (
    pd.wide_to_long(a, stubnames=['A', 'B', 'C'], sep='-', i='ID', j='to_drop')
        .droplevel(level='to_drop')
        .reset_index()
)

     ID   A   B   C
0  ID_1  a1  b1  c1
1  ID_1  a2  b2  c2
```

Alternatively [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), split the columns on '-' with [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
b = a.set_index('ID')
b.columns = b.columns.str.split('-', expand=True)
b = b.stack().droplevel(-1).reset_index()

     ID   A   B   C
0  ID_1  a1  b1  c1
1  ID_1  a2  b2  c2
```

Comment: The second approach worked like a charm for me as I have multiple stubnames and because the code is the most concise of all other answers. Still it was very informative to discover this new pandas function (wide_to_long). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This approach will generate some intermediate columns which will be removed later on.

First bring down those labels (A-1,...) from the header into a column

```
df = pd.melt(a, id_vars=['ID'], var_name='label')
```

Then split the label into character and number

```
df[['char', 'num']] = df['label'].str.split('-', expand=True)
```

Finally drop the label, `set_index` before `unstack`, and take care of the final table formats.

```
df.drop('label', axis=1)\
    .set_index(['ID', 'num', 'char'])\
    .unstack()\
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)\
    .reset_index()\
    .drop('num', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which abstracts the reshaping process and is also efficient:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

a.pivot_longer(index="ID", names_to=".value", names_pattern="(.).+")
 
     ID   A   B   C
0  ID_1  a1  b1  c1
1  ID_1  a2  b2  c2
```

The `.value` tells the function which part of the columns to retain. It takes its cue from the `names_pattern`, which should be a regular expression with groups, the grouped regex are what stay as headers. In this case, the first letter of each column is what we are interested in, which is represented by `(.)`.

Another option, with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer), is to use the `names_sep` parameter:

```py
(a.pivot_longer(index="ID", names_to=(".value", "num"), names_sep="-")
.drop(columns="num")
)

     ID   A   B   C
0  ID_1  a1  b1  c1
1  ID_1  a2  b2  c2
```

Again, only values in the columns associated with `.value` remain as headers.

Comment: At this stage I prefer to not use any external dependency so I chose the answer of Henry Ecker. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import math
df=pd.DataFrame(data={k:[i*k for i in range(1,5)] for k in range (1,9)})
assert(df.shape[1]%2==0)
df_1=df.iloc[:,0:math.floor(df.shape[1]/2)]
df_2=df.iloc[:,math.floor(df.shape[1]/2):]
df_2.columns=df_1.columns
df_sum=pd.concat((df_1,df_2),axis=0)
display(df_sum)
```

Like this?[image]